# Error Where Trying to Update Column Using Trigger in Same Table

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have been trying to get the following trigger to update the price based on a discount rate when that rate is updated.

```
create or replace trigger discount_change 
  before update on maintain
  for each row
begin
  if :NEW.discount_rate != :OLD.discount_rate
  then
    update maintain m
    set m.discount_price = :NEW.discount_rate * :OLD.price
    where m.m_id = :NEW.m_id;
  end if;
end;
```

As this is an exercise, these are in the same table (sadly) and when I attempt to do this I am consistently getting the error:

> table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

I've been combing these forums looking for the answer and as far as I have researched, this shouldn't be throwing this error as I am not selecting anything from the table. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to make the column discount_price as computed column so there is no need to define trigger for its updation

Comment: Wish I could but this is an exercise in which we are meant to be practicing triggers. I know why the reasons behind the error but I still can't figure out how to get around it.